# App Link URL for Facebook App Invite

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I want to generate App Link URL for my Facebook game app so players can send game invitation for all their friends.

After referencing Facebook SDK, I have this kind of code:

[image]

In above AppInvite function, first parameter require App Link URL that I was trying to generate.

For this purpose, I gone through multiple posts like these:

['Missing app link URL' on Facebook app invite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918858/missing-app-link-url-on-facebook-app-invite)

[what is AppLink URL in FB.Mobile.AppInvite in Facebook SDK for Unity? and how to get it? or make it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37279203/what-is-applink-url-in-fb-mobile-appinvite-in-facebook-sdk-for-unity-and-how-to)

But I can't able to get success in this because I can't able to generate App Link URL.

Comment: Hi Siddharth. Please try to keep your posts succinct here and refrain from politenesses and chatty material; we try to aim for brevity here. In particular, there is no need to add "please help me" and other variants, since your volunteer audience may interpret it as a form of begging. You may be interested [in this post about confident questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions). Thanks for reading!

Comment: Thank you sir for providing confidence :)